# List all uploaded images from cloudinary in react app

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary

I want to display all the images in my cloudinary gallery in to my react app. Can I call the function directly like this?

```
showImages = () =>{
   cloudinary.v2.api.resources({
       cloud_name: CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
       upload_preset: CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET,
       api_key: CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
       api_secret: CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
       type: 'upload'}, function(error, result){
       console.log("herrrrrrrrrreeeeeeeeeeeee",error,result);
   });
```

}

---

It gives me this error.

```
Failed to load https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dashboardui/resources/image/upload?: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there isn't a method to list resources in React. The method you're using is specific to the Cloudinary Node SDK. If you have a server tied into your app then you can use the resources method to list the images.

Comment: Then, is there a way to display all the images in javascript? And why can't we use this node method in my react app? It is writte in javascript only.

Answer (score 0):

The way to accomplish pulling images from cloudinary is to Tag the images, you need to go to media library which will display all the photos and tag photos with keyword eg "upload" which you can then use in the GET axios request. I was successfully able to pull the tagged images. You would need some css to align the images

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { CloudinaryContext, Transformation, Image } from 'cloudinary-react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            gallery: []
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        // Request for images tagged xmas       
        axios.get('https://res.cloudinary.com/<cloudname>/image/list/<tag_keyword>.json')
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data.resources);
                this.setState({gallery: res.data.resources});
            });
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="main">
                <h1>Galleria</h1>
                <div className="gallery">
                    <CloudinaryContext cloudName="cloud_name">
                        {
                            this.state.gallery.map(data => {
                                return (
                                    <div className="responsive" key={data.public_id}>
                                        <div className="img">
                                            <a target="_blank" href={`https://res.cloudinary.com/<cloudname>/image/upload/${data.public_id}.jpg`}>
                                                <Image publicId={data.public_id}>
                                                    <Transformation
                                                        crop="scale"
                                                        width="300"
                                                        height="200"
                                                        dpr="auto"
                                                        responsive_placeholder="blank"
                                                    />
                                                </Image>
                                            </a>
                                            <div className="desc">Created at {data.created_at}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </CloudinaryContext>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why you shouldn't use this code in the browser is that you should never expose your cloud's **secret** on the client side.

Therefore, you should think about separating the code to retrieve resources from Cloudinary to your server code. You can expose the results of this code to your client using express (for example).

The Cloudinary API makes it possible to retrieve resources using the Search endpoint so you can retrieve them based on a variety of criteria.

see: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/search_api